# Managing memory usage in a purrr walk loop

Tags: r, memory, purrr

I have code that looks similar to below:

```
purrr::walk(directories, function(directory) {
    purrr::walk(list.files(directory), function(file) {
        DoStuff %>% DoMoreStuff %>% write.csv(file)
        })
})
```

When I run this function, I have approximately 10-12 GB of RAM available. None of these files or their outputs are larger than 4 GB.  Yet I notice when I watch my memory usage as this function is proceeding that my RAM usage slowly creeps higher and higher until I reach a memory allocation limit after 7-8 files are processed. This doesn't make sense to me because I would think if I'm not saving an object, I should essentially have a "clean slate" everytime a `.csv` is written and a new loop occurs. Am I doing something incorrectly? I assume my interpretation of how memory works is also incorrect.

Comment: Can you try with `fwrite` and `lapply`

Comment: sure, ill try it out and let you know

Comment: It was able to complete without running out of memory allocation, so that's an improvement. Still seems like it is using more than it "should". If I am manipulating my data heavily (7.5 million rows, 300 variables) in terms of making everything lower case, converting data types, converting values to NA, etc. prior to writing it to a CSV, do you think there is much improvement in memory performance by using `data.table` instead of the `tidyverse` suite of functions and tibbles?

Comment: It's very frustrating, not sure how to best address the issue. I think alot of the RAM usage is due to copy-on-modify so I figure if I switch to data.table and modify by reference I may be able to get around that.

Comment: @akrun, so i have spent the last 24 hours (nearly) completely rewriting my codebase to utilize `data.table` and the memory efficiency and speed are lightyears better. It never requires more than 1gb of ram because I'm avoiding copy on modify and I only ever need to load one column into memory when I perform the various operations. Still have a couple things left to convert that might be hard but I'm sure ill post an SO question if I need help lol, you've been answering all my questions.

Comment: The way I deal with the situation is 1) have a single column dataset with another rowid or sequence column as fst, 2) read only the column needed, do transform or merge with another.. 3) when a particular column is needed, use the rowid to subset those column, 4) also use intersect on the rowids if multiple column datasets are loaded.  In that way, some of the initial operations can be optimized

Comment: If you time to demonstrate a reprex for that (or a GitHub), I'd love to see it.

Comment: It is a proprietrary code for a company, so I can't share it.  sorry